# How to prevent children from triggering a mouse over event?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `TabItem` with a `Grid` and `CheckBox` children.

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="First" Style="{DynamicResource CustomTabItemStyle}">
        <Grid>
            <CheckBox Content="Check Me"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Check Me 2"/>
        </Grid>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

I'm styling the `TabItem` and setting the `IsMouseOver` trigger to change the `TabItem` background color like this:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
<MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
<Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
<Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
</MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
<Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Background}"/>
<Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0.1"/>
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="{StaticResource TabItem.MouseOver.Border}"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0"/>
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0"/>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

The problem is that when the mouse is over the checkbox the background color change triggers. It happens with every child element under `TabItem`

I tried setting a `Tag="TabItemParent"` to the `TabItem`, but it didn't work. I tried many other conditions together such as `IsMouseDirectlyOver`, but I can't get it to work only when the mouse is over the actual `TabItem` and not any of its child elements. Also tried with C# `MouseEnter` and `MouseLeave`, it does the same.

Looked online too and couldn't find anything on the topic.

Ideally it would be best to have a fully XAML solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed this line from the style:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=templateRoot}" Value="true"/>
```

It seems that `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}` will target all children and the parent.